# how can I get the only entered values from an array?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to make a program to print a multiplication table in which the user enters the number of table he wants (for example 3) , also enters the values of table he wants( 2,6,5 (random/unordered)), also enters the range of multiplier.
my code is printing all the elements present in the array.
please help me. ThankYou.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

class Addition
{
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    int j=0,k=0;
    Scanner obj=new Scanner(System.in);
    int arr[]=new int[32];
    System.out.println("how many multiplication table do you want to print ? ");
    int n=obj.nextInt();
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter number whos table you want ");
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            arr[j]=obj.nextInt(); break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Enter range of multiplier");
    int range=obj.nextInt();
    
    for(int l=0;l<=arr[j];l++)
    {
        for(k=1;k<=range;k++)
        {
            System.out.println(" "+l+" * "+k+" = "+l*k);
            
        }
    }
}
```

}

> the output I want will look somewhat like this(
> how many multiplication table do you want to print ? =3 and on entering numbers 2,5,6 and range=4)

```
2x1=2 
2x2=4  
2x3=6   
2x4=8
   
5x1=5  
5x2=10  
5x3=15  
5x4=20

6x1=6  
6x2=12  
6x3=18  
6x4=24
```

Comment: Please specify your problem clearly. It is not clear from your description.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Even if i run the program in compiler, I am unable to understand your input statements.Please make it clear.

Comment: `j` will only ever be only ever be `0` (initially), then `1`. Once set to `1`, it will never have another value. Now look at the code to see why that is. *Hint:* `break;`

Comment: What I was trying to explain was.... I want an output in which I get multiplication table of desired random numbers.. example. if i choose 3 numbers( 6,8,9) and chosen range =3; then I want something like 6*1=6;6*2=12;6*3=18 and same for number 8 and 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few adjustments to carry out what i think you trying to accomplish. you could use an arraylist seen below:

```
class Addition{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int j=0,k=0;
    Scanner obj=new Scanner(System.in);
    
    ArrayList<Integer> typeMultiplicationTable = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    
    //used Arraylist instead of an array
    //int arr[]=new int[32]; 
    System.out.println("how many table? ");
    int n=obj.nextInt();
    
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter number whos table you want ");
        for(j=0;j<=n;j++)
        {
            typeMultiplicationTable.add(obj.nextInt());
            break;
            //arr[j]=obj.nextInt(); break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Enter range");
    int range=obj.nextInt();
    
    for(int l=0;l<=typeMultiplicationTable.size()-1;l++)
    {
        for(k=0;k<=range;k++)
        {
            System.out.println(" "+typeMultiplicationTable.get(l)+" * "+k+" = "+typeMultiplicationTable.get(l)*k);
        }
    }
}}
```

and if you do end up using an array, you could achieve it as follows - i ended up removing one of the for loops.

```
class Addition{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner obj=new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("how many table? ");
    int n=obj.nextInt();
    
    int arr[]=new int[n]; 

        for(int j=0;j<=arr.length-1;j++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter number whos table you want ");
            arr[j]=obj.nextInt();
        }
    
    System.out.println("Enter range");
    int range=obj.nextInt();
    
    for(int l=0;l<=arr.length-1;l++)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<=range;k++)
        {
            System.out.println(" "+arr[l]+" * "+k+" = "+arr[l]*k);
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: can you please explain where I was doing it wrong? please.